# Read text files in a folder into a martix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some text files in a folder and I need to read all of them into a matrix, but when I use the following code:

```
with open('E:/UGC/Animationpsnr_bitrate_0.txt','r') as file:
    psnr_bitrate = file.readlines()
```

It produces an `str` list but I need to save them as float variables. In the following I put a sample of text file content:

```
33.773083 36.171250 38.032833 39.589417 40.937167 42.214250
45.867417 49.271917 51.478500 53.247500 54.981250 56.507333
48.421417 51.848833 54.390500 56.687750 58.457333 60.029583
48.790583 52.691333 55.534750 57.793250 59.953167 61.538500
```

Suppose I have 20 text files in a folder with contents like above. finally, I need to read all files and save them in a matrix that has 6 columns and the rows are all the text file values. could you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to iterate over all the pathnames of text files in the folder `UGC`, then using [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) you can load the txt files as a numpy array, finally use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) to vertically stack all the arrays

```
import glob

np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/UGC/*.txt')])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will find any files within the directory that matches `bitrate*.txt`.
It will then iterate over each line, convert each value to a float and add it to the list `data`

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\YourFolder')
print(path)

data = []

for filepath in path.glob('bitrate*.txt'):
    with open(filepath,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            data.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
            
print(data)
```

Pandas/numpy not required here.

Answer (score 0):

you can split each line and convert it to float like this:

```
matrix = []
with open('E:/UGC/Animationpsnr_bitrate_0.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        matrix.append([float(value) for value in line.strip().split()])
```

for multiple files add one more for loop at top and read each file and append the contents on matrix list.